# How to hide div

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net

I need some script.

1. To hide a div by clicking anywhere on the page
2. To hide a div by clicking on button, images or particular script
3. To hide a div by clicking anywhere on the page ( when div contain any other script)

---

I am currently using

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#div").click(function () {

            document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'none';

      });

    });
    </script>
```

This working fine why div contain images, but it not working when div contain script like advertisement script such as chitika, adsense or any other

Please tell how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this use `this` this selector is used to hide the clicked `div`

```
$("#div").click(function () {
          $(this).hide();
      });
```

Comment: Hello please download it from here, www40.zippyshare.com/v/YxRgLqsL/file.html

or
Here is a code 1 . pastebin.com/Ji8xLH24 2. pastebin.com/ZERQWnGa 3. pastebin.com/9diDeMZH

Answer (score 0):

To hide it, you would do some javascript and

Also you need to include Jquery library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("#YourDivID").click(function (){     //inspect the ID might differ.
      $(this).hide();
  });
```

Comment: did you added the basic Jquery library which I said im my post

Comment: Do u have inherited master page ?? And also show your code where you are writing?

Comment: I need to hide the div after one click on the page.

I am using your code and my div in same page.

Comment: Hello please download it from here,

http://www40.zippyshare.com/v/YxRgLqsL/file.html

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma: Paste your aspx code here http://jsfiddle.net/ 

As I am not able to know where is your code

Comment: I have added a comment there. please download and checkout

Comment: Here is a code 
1 . http://pastebin.com/Ji8xLH24
2. http://pastebin.com/ZERQWnGa
3. http://pastebin.com/9diDeMZH

Comment: why are you adding `doctype` when it is an aspx page

Comment: doctype i added simple, just ignore that.

Comment: means ??, so what to do ??

Answer (score 0):

This code answers to your first and third question:

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
document.getElementById(name of your div).style.display = 'none';
});
```

And the second question:

```html
<div id="testdiv">test</div>
<script>
    function hidediv(){
    document.getElementById("testdiv").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<input type=button value="Click me" onclick="hidediv()">
```

Comment: What part is not working? I tested the second part, and you have to edit div name in the first part

Comment: please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914297/how-to-hide-div/28915480?noredirect=1#comment46089654_28914340