# Hide div after clicked clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div which i am trying to close when someone clicks on it.

```js
$(#div).click(function () {
    document.getElementById('#div').style.display = 'none';
});
```

The problem is it works fine till i use images. when there is script inside div it do not works.

Comment: So do you have an element with the ID `#div`, including the hash, and did you add quotes to the jQuery selector in the actual code, as it stands it looks like it would throw an error ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914297/how-to-hide-div)

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: Check out the person asking both the question...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#div').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

As a side note, I wouldn't use "div" as an id for a div. I'd use something more specific like "disappearingDiv".

**Here is an example:**

```js
$('#div').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
#div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#666666;
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
<script>
$("#div").click(function () {
document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'none';
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
$("#div").click(function () {
    $(this).css("display", 'none');
});
```

... or ...

```
$("#div").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Both of these use jQuery optimally.

Answer (score 0):

simplify things

```html
<div id="div" onclick="this.style.display = 'none';">
  Here is the div
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgDKJeeHPHtfNrm4Z9ghtI-8l6Bpdb-Vf0vcyk4cM9ZWSWWJsXYxmOQ3Q">
  </div>
```